# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment, android-inflate

I want to inflate a layout containing a single seekBar. in this way, I've created a java class that extends fragment class and then I inflate the layout. but the following error occurred:

Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

```
warming.XML is in the following:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="217dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="349dp"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="300"
        app:activeTrackColor="#ff4500"
        app:inactiveTrackColor="#fbb999" >

    </com.google.android.material.slider.Slider>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and firstPage.java that inflate layout warming.XML is in the following:

```
public class firstPage extends Fragment {
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.warming,container,false);
   }
}
```

using the following code, I want to execute the firstPage.java class:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new firstPage()).commit();
```

what's the matter? can anyone help me? I've searched for this problem in StackOverflow and some other websites, and there were similar questions but no one can solve my problem.

**Update**

full Stack Trace is here:

```
04-16 12:45:37.991 18832-18832/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-16 12:45:37.991 18832-18832/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:18832
04-16 12:45:38.132 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/arm
04-16 12:45:38.443 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-16 12:45:38.513 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-16 12:45:38.513 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-16 12:45:38.914 18832-18848/com.example.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3__release_AU (I3fa967cfef)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.28.00.02
    Build Date: 09/29/15 Tue
    Local Branch: mybranch14683032
    Remote Branch: quic/master
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-16 12:45:51.663 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 18832
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.myapplication.firstPage.onCreateView(firstPage.java:16)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at com.example.myapplication.firstPage.onCreateView(firstPage.java:16) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at com.example.myapplication.firstPage.onCreateView(firstPage.java:16) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 11: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300b4 a=3}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:482)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:71)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.processAttributes(Slider.java:365)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.<init>(Slider.java:261)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.<init>(Slider.java:252)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at com.example.myapplication.firstPage.onCreateView(firstPage.java:16) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
04-16 12:45:53.565 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication D/Process: killProcess, pid=18832
04-16 12:45:53.670 18832-18832/com.example.myapplication D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:113 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

and in the following is the Build.gradle code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and if you want to ask me "why don't you use the "material:1.3.0" version", I can say that because of rendering problem associated with Navigation Drawer Layout, according to some instruction in StackOverFlow, I changed it to "material:1.2.0-alpha02" and rendering problem was solved.
I ask that question in another post. you can access that question in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095956/com-google-android-materialmaterial1-2-0-alpha02-does-not-include-some-instr

and here is Theme.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti full stack trace was added. thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the 1.3.0? What is your app theme?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti no, I am using 1.2.0-alpha02 version.

Comment: Use at least a stable version 1.2.0 or 1.2.1

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I also add Gradle code in the update section.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti hello, I changed the material version to 1.3.0(newest version). but the same error is shown.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti sorry, I am beginner to android studio. what do you mean by theme? I think you mean theme.xml:

<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

**********************************************************************************
do you need more information?

Comment: Yes the theme used in your Activity and defined in themes.xml

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I added Theme.xml full resource at the end of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, after a lot of searching, finally I found out there is a simillar object to slider named  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar> in android studio. so, you can use this object instead of "slider" object. so there is no inflating error in this way.

Answer (score 22):

I created the following theme:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Add attributes here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/itimalia_pink_califoria</item>
</style>
```

then:

```
   <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"/>
```

and it works.

Answer (score 9):

If your application theme is not derived from Material Design, you can get past the runtime crash by assigning the following theme to the Slider widget.

android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 6):

It is due to your base app theme is not a child of the material theme. In my case, I was using the app theme of Appcompat child..but I was using a view that inherits everything from the MaterialComponenets theme. And it was throwing the error.

App theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   ...
</style>
```

So I created another style as,

```
<style name="WD_Slider" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

and referred that style in slider view as,

```
android:theme="@style/WD_Slider"
```

With this approach, you can use any view which is not a child of your app theme and override the required theme exactly when you use it in XML at the view level.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `app:trackColorActive` and `app:trackColorInactive` instead of
`app:activeTrackColor` and `app:inactiveTrackColor`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        ...
        app:trackColorActive="#ff4500"
        app:trackColorInactive="#fbb999"/>
```

Comment: when I replace your code and I run my application, my application is not executed and it also does not give any error. but when I deleted  the mentioned XML code from warming.XML, I get the same error. 
thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upgrading to `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0` did not help. As stated above, the only solution was to set `android:theme` to something, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This has given me exact tracking in kotlin

```
seekBar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int,
                                       fromUser: Boolean) {
            
            tvProgress.text = "CAD "+ progress.toString()
            val bounds: Rect = seekBar.thumb.bounds
            tvProgress.x = (seekBar.left + bounds.left + seekBar.thumbOffset).toFloat()

         }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
         }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            seekBarValue = seekBar.progress
         }
    })




<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                 android:background="@drawable/bg_box_border_unselected"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:text="CAD 20"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvProgress"
                 android:max="28"
                android:maxHeight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:min="20"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:progress="20"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                android:thumb="@drawable/ic_thumb_seekbar" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```