# How to create Navigation drawer using <material:1.3.0>

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, navigation-drawer

I want to make a Navigation drawer using <implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'> in android studio. in fact when I use <implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'> , I get the error in in the below image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkfJ.png)

but according to some instruction in StackOverFlow like in the below link:

[how to solve render problem Path.op() not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809654/how-to-solve-render-problem-path-op-not-supported)

I decided to use com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02 version in build.gradle.  but I think this cause some other problem. for example in the below link:

[Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114506/binary-xml-file-line-9-binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-com-goog?noredirect=1#comment118644034_67114506)

when we use com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02, we have problem in executing some object like Slider.
so can someone give a solution for this problem? can someone make a Navigation drawer using material:1.3.0 version?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking really. Have you tried to implement a Navigation drawer and encountered an issue or you are just asking if you can create a Navigation Drawer with a specific version of Material library?

Comment: @hardartcore I get rendering error when I want to implement navigation drawer in material:1.3.0. but I can not use alpha version(material:1.2.0-alpha02) because I think alpha version cause some problems like the second link. so I insist on creating a Navigation Drawer with material:1.3.0 version?

Comment: Without an exact error which you get with your implementation we can't really help.
Post they way you are creating your Navigation Drawer and the error you get.

Comment: @hardartcore one image that shows the rendering error was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved.
but at the first, I have to migrate to androidX. after that, no randering error get appeared in the navigation drawer's layout when using material:1.3.0 in Build.gradle .